# how to use async and await in actions on google and API

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, actions-on-google

I am making an actions on google that uses an API and I am using request promise to build it . But in calling api I calculated average time it takes is 0.5 sec so I am trying to await it for 0.5 second , but I am getting an error while deploying  this code

```
 .then( async(parseBody)=>{

        for(var i=0;i<parseBody.passengers.length;i++){
            data.push(parseBody.passengers[i].current_status);

        }   
        console.log(data);
        // sleep.sleep(0.5);
        await sleep(2000)
        conv.ask(`Ticket's current status is ${data}`);
```

and the error is `32:33  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>`

Please help me to find a better solution of this ,I am working with API's for the first time

Comment: You should await the promise instead of doing something in the then.

Comment: _I calculated average time it takes is 0.5 sec_ .... Wait. Why don't you use a regular promise instead and use a callback when it is finished?

Comment: @JaromandaX isn't that nodejs?

Comment: Where and how are you deploying this code?

Comment: @Prisoner I am deploying it in firebase,using command line

Answer (score 0):

Working with promises you can concatenate more .then()

So, you can do something like this:

```
.then( (data) => {
    //do stuff with data
    return data;
})
.then( (data) => {
    //Here data is what you returned in then() before
    //do stuff with data
});
```

BTW, the error you getting is because you heve syntax error in in your code, it should be:

```
.then( async(parseBody)=>{
    for(var i=0;i<parseBody.passengers.length;i++){
        data.push(parseBody.passengers[i].current_status);

    }   
    console.log(data);
    // sleep.sleep(0.5);
    await sleep(2000)
    conv.ask(`Ticket's current status is ${data}`);
});
```

Comment: are you saying the missing `});` at the end of the code in the question is the cause for the error?

Comment: @JaromandaX exactly. Assuming that before that then() there is a valid promise init

Comment: missing the final `});` would not cause that parsing error

Comment: @JaromandaX just tested. Same error. It's quite evident. If the function syntax is not correct, it is not interpreted as a function, so the parser does not expect that `=>`

Comment: weird, I get a bunch of different errors - I'll defer to your wisdom

Answer (score 0):

You indicated you are deploying this "using Firebase", and probably the default configuration environment for it. This default configuration is for Node 6, however you are using "async" in your code, which is available in Node 8.

You can switch your project to Node 8, which is still in Beta support for Firebase. In your `package.json` file, you can add this property to the JSON object:

```
"engines": {"node": "8"}
```

Alternately, you can try to rewrite this without async/await. I haven't tested it (mostly because I have no idea what `sleep()` function you're using) but something more like this:

```
.then( parseBody =>{
    for(var i=0;i<parseBody.passengers.length;i++){
        data.push(parseBody.passengers[i].current_status);

    }   
    console.log(data);
    return sleep(2000);
})
.then( () => {
    conv.ask(`Ticket's current status is ${data}`);
});
```

(Mind you, it doesn't make sense why you're waiting at all. It seems very strange that you'll get results back, but the results aren't valid for some period of time after that.)